# Redirect /api requests to port 3000 using NGINX (Docker)

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect the requests to the /api to the node app running on localhost:3000 using NGINX

I'm trying to redirect the requests using proxy_pass

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name  localhost;

   root /var/www/mydomain/html;
   index index.html index.htm;

   location /api {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
   }
}
```

If I access localhost in my browser I see the frontend application, so that's correct.

If I hit http://127.0.0.1:3000 (or localhost:3000) I get a response from the node API, so that's correct.

But when I try to access localhost/api I get the following error:

> [error] 6#6: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting >to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api >HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "localhost"

EDIT:

I'm using a docker-compose to manage the services:

```
services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx-local
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx.dev.dockerfile
    volumes:
      ...
    ports: 
      - '80:80'
    networks:
      - local-network

  node:
    container_name: node-api
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: .docker/node.dockerfile
    ports: 
      - '3000:3000'
    networks:
      - local-network
```

Comment: Are you in docker?

Comment: yes, I'm using the nginx docker image

Comment: So you have a `docker-compose` with a node service and nginx service correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Well the `node` service is not on localhost in the `nginx` docker image

Comment: @ShawnC. I edited my question including the docker-compose file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the `docker-compose` file the `nginx` config for needs to be changed to

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /var/www/mydomain/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://node-api:3000/;
    }
}
```

This is due to the separate `docker` image for the node application. So you need to use the proxy pass to point to the correct location.